# Accessing an observable stream after it has completed in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, observable, indexeddb

I've been writing a simple app that makes use of IndexedDB (thanks to Robisim for his sample app whose code I borrowed https://github.com/robisim74/angular2indexedDB) but am having trouble accessing the array of objects for my component asynchronously. Even though I'm able to iterate over the ITEMS in the html page using the | async pipe - I cannot seem to work with the object array in the ts file.  I have tried subscribing to the observable but it doesn't succeed in doing anything. Can anyone please help me select the first object in the object array when the observable is finished loading from IndexedDB?

Home Component

getSchedule() {

```
this.selectedSchedule = this.entity.schedule[0];
```

}

get ITEMS(): Observable {

```
return new Observable((observer: Observer<Array<Item>>) => {


  observer.next(this.entity.schedule);
  console.log(this.entity.schedule);
  observer.complete();
});
```

}

Code in App Component Opening the DB

openDB(dbName: string) {

```
// Opens the database.
this.indexedDB.openDBAsync(dbName, 1).forEach(

  // Next.
  (readyState: string) => {

    console.log('IndexedDB service: opening db: ' + readyState);

  }, null

).then(

  () => {

    // Gets all records from "TodoStore".
    this.indexedDB.getAllRecordsAsync("ItemStore").forEach(

      // Next.
      (record: Item) => {

        // Adds next record to the Todos entity.
        if (record != null) {

          this.entity.addItem(record);

        }

      }, null

    ).then(() => console.log('IndexedDB service: obtaining of all records completed.'))
  }

);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because access to IndexedDB is asynchronous, the problem is only *when* you call the `getSchedule` method: in fact, if you call the method for example from the constructor, the `openDB` method has definitely not been completed yet. Try to call the method from a button and you'll see that it works:

```
<button type="button" (click)="getSchedule()">Get schedule</button>
```

Once you understand this, if you need the data of the db to be available in the components at application load, you might, for example, use APP_INITIALIZER, which waits for the condition to be satisfied before uploading the app:

**AppModule**

```
@Injectable() export class IndexedDB {

    constructor(public indexedDB: IndexedDBService, public entity: Entity) { }

    load(): Promise<void> {
        // Opens the "Angular2IndexedDB" database. If it doesn't exist, it will be created.
        let promise: Promise<any> = new Promise((resolve: any) => {
            this.indexedDB.openDBAsync("Angular2IndexedDB", 1).forEach(
                (readyState: string) => {
                    console.log('IndexedDB service: opening db: ' + readyState);
                }, null
            ).then(
                () => {
                    // Gets all records.
                    this.indexedDB.getAllRecordsAsync("ItemStore").forEach(
                        // Next.
                        (record: Item) => {
                            // Adds next record to the entity.
                            if (record != null) {
                                this.entity.addItem(record);
                            }
                        }, null
                    ).then(() => {
                        resolve(true);
                        console.log('IndexedDB service: obtaining of all records completed.');
                    });
                });
        });

        return promise;
    }
}

export function initIndexedDB(indexedDB: IndexedDB): Function {
    return () => indexedDB.load();
}

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        IndexedDBService,
        Entity,
        IndexedDB,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initIndexedDB,
            deps: [IndexedDB],
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and remove the `openDB` method from AppComponent.

If you need to load data for a specific component, instead, you could use Angular router Resolve.

Comment: Hey Rob, thank you so much for answering my question. I have been trying to implement the answer for the past couple of days. One of the things that happened was that the entire app loaded into a blank white screen and I wasn't getting any errors in console or the terminal. I looked at other cases of APP_INITIALIZER and am still kind of lost.

Comment: I just got it to work! Looked at the app in your repo and provided for IndexedDB and it works to perfection, able to pick up the first item on load of the application. Again thanks so much!